# Why OpenProcess Gives me a non-NULL HANDLE for a non existing pid?

Tags: c++, winapi

I reduced the code as much as I could to keep it [sscce](http://sscce.org/)
What this code does:

- Launch windows notepad with `CreateProcess`
- Pause. So windows got some time to init notepad
- Kill notepad with `TerminateProcess` on the Handle we got from `CreateProcess`.
- Wait for the process handle to terminate, because `TerminateProcess` is async
- Call `OpenProcess` on the dead pid
- Play with my zombie...

You can easily check (before OpenProcess) in debug that the given Pid is nowhere to be found in either the task manager or processExplorer. But no other windows API functions seems to accept this Pid

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "Psapi.h"
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

typedef unsigned long PID;
typedef const std::string& P_PATH;

// Launch an executable given by a path and set a few infomatives stuffs passed as ref parameters
bool launch_process(P_PATH path, STARTUPINFO& info, PROCESS_INFORMATION& processInfo, HANDLE& hProcess, PID& pid)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
    std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(path.begin(), path.end());
    const wchar_t* widecstr = widestr.c_str();

    LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(widecstr);

    if (CreateProcess(szCmdline, NULL, NULL, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
    {
        hProcess = processInfo.hProcess;
        pid = processInfo.dwProcessId;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Setup
    // -----
    bool OK = false;

    STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PID pid = 0;

    // launch notepad
    // --------------
    OK = launch_process("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\notepad.exe", info, processInfo, hProcess, pid);
    assert(OK);

    // wait a bit
    // ----------
    system("PAUSE");
    SetLastError(0);

    // get Handle on notepad
    // ---------------------
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE | SYNCHRONIZE, false, static_cast<DWORD>(pid));
    std::cout << "Error: " <<  GetLastError() << std::endl;

    // Kill notepad
    // ------------
    UINT exitCode = 0;
    DWORD dwWaitResult = 0;

    SetLastError(0);
    OK = TerminateProcess(hProcess, exitCode);
    std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    // ensure everything went well ( we need to wait because TerminateProcess is asynchronous )
    if (!OK || (dwWaitResult != WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, INFINITE)))
        return -1;

    // Cleanup
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    hProcess = nullptr;
    processInfo.hProcess = nullptr;

    // Ya know what let's reopen the pid I just killed 
    // ( you can see that notepad was started then killed, you can check the pid does not exist in either the task manager or processExplorer )
    SetLastError(0);
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE | SYNCHRONIZE, false, static_cast<DWORD>(pid));
    std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    // Yeah I can speak to the deads! 
    if (hProcess != nullptr)
    {
        LPWSTR szProcessName = L"";
        GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, szProcessName, sizeof szProcessName);

        char c_szText[MAX_PATH];
        wcstombs(c_szText, szProcessName, wcslen(szProcessName) + 1);

        // But the deads have no names
        std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Zombie Name: " << c_szText << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't close the handles in the PROCESS_INFORMATION so the process object has not yet been destroyed.

Comment: Took your comment into account... same problem.

Comment: I don't see where you close the thread handle.

Comment: @RaymondChen, Below the cleanup comment, I added 3 lines

Comment: What is the question? You aren't asking anything.

Comment: @Ben As stated in the title...

    hProcess = OpenProcess
Should not give me a non-null handle. why does it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. It's not appearing in the list of processes in Task Manager because it has terminated. Task Manager doesn't show zombies (this behaviour differs from e.g. Linux `ps -Af f` which does show zombies).
2. It's still there and accessible to `OpenProcess` because the process object has not been destroyed, i.e. it is in the zombie state. This will be because another process has an open handle to it. For example,

   - an antivirus, which may call OpenProcess to get information to assess if the application is malicious, or
   - Process Monitor, which gets all sorts of information, probably some of which it calls OpenProcess to get, or
   - the DWM, which I imagine, but do not know, calls OpenProcess to get information on whether the application supports e.g. high DPI mode and so forth, or
   - any number of other applications may have called OpenProcess previously and have a still open handle.

Morals:

- Don't expect the process object to be destroyed as soon as you close your handle, because yours is not the only handle.
- Zombie state is a perfectly legitimate state for a process to be in. All processes will be in the zombie state if they have terminated, and someone is waiting to read their exit code with `GetExitCodeProcess`, or have any other interest in the state of the process. Typically once the exit code has been read, interest in the process wanes, handles are closed, and finally the process will be destroyed.
- The PID can be reused once the process is destroyed. (Conversely, the PID cannot be reused until all handles are closed). In Windows, the kernel prefers low numbered PIDs and will reuse them quite quickly. This behaviour differs from Linux which prefers incrementing PIDs and won't reuse them until the maximum value is reached.
- If you want the handle to the process, don't close it.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. this is much more useful that the "stop writing buggy code" I got from someone else...

Comment: It should also be noted that (AFAIK) these "zombie" process objects aren't particularly resource-heavy.  The process address space has already been reclaimed, all the handles are gone, and so on - all that's left is some accounting information.